# GWT Safe HTML Framework: When to use, and why?

Tags: java, html, gwt, xss

In reading JavaDocs and various GWT articles, I've occassionally run into the following `Safe*` classes:

- `SafeHtml`
- `SafeHtmlBuilder`

It looks like `SafeHtml` is somehow used when creating a new `Widget` or `Composite`, and helps ensure that the Widget/Composite doesn't execute any scripts on the client-side. Is this the case, or am I way off-base? Can someone provide a code example of `SafeHtml` being used properly in action?

If so, then what's the point of `SafeHtmlBuilder`? Do you use it inside of a Widget to somehow "build up" safe HTML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to view `SafeHtml` is as a `String` where any HTML markup has been appropriately escaped.  This protects against Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks as it ensures, for example, if someone enters their name in a form as `<SCRIPT>alert('Fail')</SCRIPT>` this is the text that gets displayed when your page is rendered rather than the JavaScript being run.

So instead of having something like:

```
String name = getValueOfName();
HTML widget = new HTML(name);
```

You should use:

```
String name = getValueOfName();
HTML widget = new HTML(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(name));
```

`SafeHtmlBuilder` is like a `StringBuilder` except that it automatically escapes HTML markup in the Strings you add.  So to extend the above example:

```
String name = getValueOfName();
SafeHtmlBuilder shb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
shb.appendEscaped("Name: ").appendEscaped(name);
HTML widget = new HTML(shb.toSafeHtml());
```

The is a good [guide to `SafeHtml` in the GWT documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml) that is worth a read.

Answer (score 8):

`SafeHtmlBuilder` is to `SafeHtml` what `StringBuilder` is to `String`.

As for the `Safe*` API, use it whenever you deal with HTML (or CSS for `SafeStyles`, or URLs for `SafeUri` and `UriUtils`), more precisely building HTML/CSS/URL from parts to be fed to the browser for parsing, with **no** exception.

Actually, we were recently discussing whether to deprecate `Element.setInnerHtml` and other similar APIs (`HasHTML`) in favor of `Element.setInnerSafeHtml` and the like (`HasSafeHtml`).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Broyer (+1) - that makes sense, although I'm missing the connection with Widgets. I *thought* the entire presentation of a GWT app was achieved by grouping Widgets together inside of display regions, and then using CSS to layout the different display regions. Can you please help me understand the connection of the Safe* API with Widgets? Are they meant to be used together? Or do they suit different use cases altogether? Thanks again!

Comment: Some widgets will use `Safe*` APIs internally, and possibly expose it externally (`HasHTML` / `HasSafeHtml`). Cells make heavy use of `SafeHtml`. They are distinct yet complementary APIs.

Comment: Thanks again (+1) - last followup: based on your answer ("*They are distinct yet complementary APIs...*") it sounds like there are use cases for SafeHtml that involve creating client-side HTML that have nothing to do with Widgets. Can you please give me a few use cases where one would use SafeHtml to build something on the client-side that does not use Widgets/Composites or have anything to do with Widgets/Composites? I guess I'm not understanding SafeHtml outside the context of Widgets. Thanks again!